# Hide only bottom view in AppBar during scroll

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I want to implement layout, which is similar to the following stub:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <View android:id="@+id/firstView"/>

        <View android:id="@+id/secondView"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And I want to achieve the following behavior: when recycler view scrolls up then only the `secondView` collapses. Whatever I tried I managed to only hide the `firstView` on scroll or both. How can I hide only the second one?

Comment: you have to use CollapsingToolbarLayout .

Answer (score 0):

Put the second view out of AppBarLayout. Wrap the second view and RecyclerView with LinearLayout and add scroll behavior. But the shortcoming is that second view can not scroll.